Connecting circuit to ground when control voltage is 0 V with a P-channel MOSFET
I'm trying to control a Playstation 2 dance game controller with an external voltage using P-channel MOSFETs and I think I am out of my element here as I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.
The PS2 controller I am using is somewhat of a black box, all I know is that if I connect one of the button traces (which seems to just sit at 3.7 V) to ground (0 V) it will connect the circuit and act as if I had pressed that button.
On the other end, I want to control this using a different controller, a Dance Pad, whose outputs constantly sit at 5 V and get pulled to ground (0 V) when you press a button. All signals I'm dealing with should be digital, and I have no need for any intermediate values other than On/Off.
I imagine I wouldn't want to just connect the two signals (3.7 V, 5 V) together and let the dance pad pull everything to ground as the voltages are a mismatch. I don't know for sure that this isn't a problem, but I feel fairly certain I can't just combine voltages like that without possible issues.
I did a little bit of research and possibly falsely came to the conclusion that I could use a P-channel MOSFET to solve this issue. I have purchased some BSS84 P-channel MOSFETs and have set them up in the following way:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For simplicity's sake I modeled the dance pad as a 5 V/0 V switch.
Clearly I was incorrect in assuming that I understood how this worked, as this doesn't seem to pull the game pads input to ground when the MOSFET gate is 0 V; the output seems to just stay off.
Why does my circuit using a PMOS not seem to work as described, and is there a better way instead of using a PMOS to pull the signal to ground when the control voltage is 0 V?
I tried setting this up with a simple LED where the source was 5 V, the drain was the LED to a resistor to ground, with moderate success, but I noticed that when the gate is 5 V, 0 V, or floating, the LED still has some light coming out. I can't seem to get it to be completely off or on.
I've done a little more looking into the circuit board for the game pad and it looks like when the signal I want comes out of the black blob on the board, it has a 100 nF cap to ground, and goes through a diode (I can't tell the exact type of diode but it looks like a fairly normal 1N4148 or similar). After that, as mentioned above, if I pull it to ground it completes the circuit and acts as a button press.

simulate this circuit
I have attempted to mock this up in the Falstad circuit simulator here, and it seems like it should theoretically work. This assumes that the signal I'm trying to tap is essentially a digital sensor with a pull-up to the 3.7 V that I'm seeing, and that it works with 3.3 V logic.

What is your question? Please write a specific question.

The circuit you provided might work, but it elevates the voltage level by about \$V_{th} + V_f\$ above GND, where \$V_{th}\$ and \$V_f\$ are the gate threshold voltage of the PMOS and forward voltage of the diode, respectively.
If you want lower voltage, i.e. ~0.7V (which is \$V_f\$) when activated, then you might want to opt for the following circuits. Note that you can get a voltage lower than 0.7V if the current through the diode is quite low like the simulation below, which is about 495mV.

The left-hand circuit is activated when 5V is supplied. The right-hand circuit is activated when 0V is supplied. The latter might be the circuit you are after. The circuits use NPN transistors, like 2N3904. You can replace them with NMOS if you wish.
You can also bypass the diode by connecting this way. This gives even lower voltage (~110mV in simulation). To decrease further, reduce the 500kΩ resistor.

With this, you can attach a switch between the diode and the GND for manual activation as well.

It's good to see that you thought things through, but you made one critical error.  For a p-channel FET to pull a load down to GND, its gate has to be pulled below GND.  The same is true if you wanted to use a PNP bipolar transistor.
The solution is to change to an n-channel FET or NPN transistor.  This solves the switch problem, but introduces another: when acting as a saturated switch (which is what you want), the control flow is inverting.  That is, to pull the load down, the gate or base has to go up.  The issue, of course, is that you want a low control signal to produce a low load switch.
The solution is two transistors in series.  The first transistor inverts the control signal, and the second transistor switches the load.  Both transistors are the same type, either n-channel or NPN.
UPDATE:  Schematic

Here are two circuits to do what you want, one with FETs and one with BJTs.  In both cases the signal from the 5 V system is inverted twice, so a low input creates a low output.
You are correct about p-channel FETs - when the gate is 0 V, the source will be at approx +2 V(depending on the transconductance characteristics of your particular FET).  The problem is that the FET cannot pull its drain lower than its source, so the output signal to the 3.7 V system will go no lower than 2 V, not the 0 V -ish you want.
The same thing is true, but flipped over, for an n-channel FET.  If the gate is at 5 V, the source will be at about 3 V, and the FET cannot pull its drain higher than that.

I've had a hard time really understanding P-Channel or PNP. My understanding was that you didn't necessarily need negative voltage, but the difference between the source and the gate had to be below 0V. So if gate was 0V, and source was say 2V, the difference would be -2V. I suppose an issue occurs when the source gets pulled to 0V which would then match the gate and close again? P-Channel and PNP continue to confuse me.

See the UPDATE.

@SenPi you are correct, as soon as you set the gate to 0V then the P-channel FET will start to switch and think of it as the Vds starts to decrease. Since drain is already at GND and source is also approaching GND, then the P-channel stop turning ON and stops between On and Off states.  But to make the P-channel keep being fully On (Vds close to zero) you would need to pull the gate negative.
